Conjugates and Images of Automorphisms in Arbitrary Extension
Let $L/k$ be a field extension and $\alpha \in L$ be algebraic. The $L$-conjugates of $\alpha$ are the other roots of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ in $L$. Wikipedia claims that

Equivalently, the $L$-conjugates of $\alpha$ are the images of $\alpha$ under the field automorphisms of L that leave fixed the elements of K.

This is certainly true for simple extensions. Indeed, given a conjugate $\alpha' \in k(\alpha)$, there exists a unique $k$-isomorphism $j : k(\alpha) \to k(\alpha') = k(\alpha)$ such that $j(\alpha) = \alpha'$. I believe it may be generalized to finite extensions with a straightforward inductive argument, though now we longer we have a bijection between the conjugates and the automorphisms themselves (only the images).
But I do not see how this could be true with an infinite extension.

When you say $L$-conjugate I assume you mean an element of $L$ which is conjugate to $\alpha$ over $K$?

This is not true, not even for finite extensions. Consider $K=\Bbb Q$, $L=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2})$. Then the $K$-automorphisms of $L$ send $\sqrt[4]{2}$ to $\pm \sqrt[4]{2}$, in particular they fix $\sqrt2$ and cannot send it to its conjugate $-\sqrt2$.
Another example for infinite extensions is given by $L=\Bbb R$, in this case $L$ has as its only automorphism the identity, so it cannot send any algebraic number to another one of its conjugates.
Note that further down in the Wikipedia article under Properties it specializes to normal field extensions in which case this is true.
